# org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate

I am working rest services with spring and hibernate,for updating employee data  using below code, but when  run I got below error

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions"
}
```

DataDaoImpl.java

```
 @Override  
   public Employee getEntityById(long id) throws  Exception {  
   session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Employee employee = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class,  
  new Long(id));  
  tx = session.getTransaction();  
 session.beginTransaction();  
  tx.commit();  
 return employee;  
 }
```

RestController.jav

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/save/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public   @ResponseBody  
 Status  saveUser(@PathVariable("id") long id,@RequestBody Employee employee) {
 Employee employeeupdate = null;  

 try {  
     employeeupdate  =   dataServices.getEntityById(id); 
     employeeupdate.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
     employeeupdate.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
     employeeupdate.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
     employeeupdate.setPhone(employee.getPhone());
     dataServices.updateEntity(employeeupdate);

       return new Status(1, "Employee updated Successfully !");  
      } catch (Exception e) {  
       // e.printStackTrace();  
       return new Status(0, e.toString());  
      }  
  }  

 @Override  
 public boolean updateEntity(Employee    employeeupdate) throws Exception {  

 session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
  tx = session.beginTransaction();  
  session.update(employeeupdate);  
  tx.commit();  
  session.close();  

    return false;  
 }
```

What mistake have I done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getEntityById(...)` method the session is not closed. Close the session using `session.close();` before returning the employee and try.

Comment: On a side note, instead of using `openSession()` you can consider using `getCurrentSession()`. With `getCurrentSession()` session is bound to the context and application doesn't need to close explicitly. Also `openSession()`always returns a new instance of `Session` while `getCurrentSession()` returns the session associated with that context.

Answer (score 0):

Don't open 2 sessions. Open just one and use it.

place the

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
tx = session.beginTransaction();
```

In the beginning of saveUser() and pass the session/transaction to the methods. Actually you don't need transaction in the getEntityById() - you change nothing.

Comment: Sorry man, but he is need a transaction for read in common case. May be in this case it is not very useful, but not using  transactions for read can  lead to problems with empty result with `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

Appart of @StanislavL answer, there are some errors in your code `getEntityById()` should be (you need close a session and place a transaction above `load()`).

```
@Override  
   public Employee getEntityById(long id) throws  Exception {  
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    tx = session.getTransaction();  
    session.beginTransaction();  
    Employee employee = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class,  
         new Long(id));  
    tx.commit();  
    session.close();
    return employee;  
 }
```

But this variant is not very correct too, you should catch an exception use a finally block and rollback a transaction. The best way is using this pattern [doInTransaction()](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/factory/HibernateSessionFactory.java#L41).

**Update**

It is better to get an entity this way

```
Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class,  id);
```

Comment: i am not only using getEntityById() method for updateuser,i am using it for retrieve user details seperatly.is it ok if i load it

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should not create session in your DAO.

Given that you are using Spring, you should avoid manually creating the Session/Transaction.  Please make use of Spring to manage the transaction and session creation, by relying on Spring's transaction control and things like `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`